# Anypoint studio crashes while configuring Authentication for Anypoint platform

Tags: anypoint-studio

I'm using Anypoint Studio 6.2.3 64bit and jre 1.8.0_112 64 bit on windows 10. When I perform the following, it crashes. I've tried java 7u79 also.

1. Rt-click on project in package explorer and select Anypoint Platform->Configure.
2. Click Add on Authentication dialog that appears.
   As soon as login appears, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please increase the java heap size and Anypoint will work perfectly fine. To update the java heap size you need to open the AnypointStudio.ini file and update the setting like below:
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
I have updated the value of Xms (minimum memory) Xmx (maximum memory) size in the configuration file.